# Magento Prototype Error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, ce-1.9.2.4

Getting this error:

```
prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
prototype.js:2304 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefinedElement.Methods.hasClassName
prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
prototype.js:5644 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
prototype.js:5734 Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
kam-black-cargo-trousers-38-inch-leg:2904 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
```

I think it could be a jquery conflict problem, could anyone suggest anything to check.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code where `element` is declared. Thank you.

Comment: `element` is being called from the prototype.js library.

Comment: ok, what are you trying to do? What is the expected result? What did you change that you started getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be carefully to use jQuery and Prototype together. 
When you initialize fancybox, instead of this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#showdiv").show();
});
```

you must try this

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("#showdiv").show();
});
```